# Маленькая проблемка с адресом

Tags: c, указатели

Вот набросал кусочек кода. Проблемка в том, что tmp не инициализируется после вызова foo. В функции foo, если result равен NULL, то надо инициализировать эту переменную. В дебагере внутри функции foo всё нормально, выделяется кусок памяти, адрес в result и так далее, но после выхода из функции, tmp так и остаётся NULL. Можно ли вообще сделать то, что я хочу? Заранее спасибо.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(double *, size_t, double *);

int main(void)
{
    const size_t size = 4;

    double *array = NULL;
    double *tmp   = NULL;

    array = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 4;

    // После вызова foo, tmp так и остаётся NULL
    foo(array, size, tmp);
    foo(array, size, array);

    int i;

    printf("array:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("array[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, array[i]);

    printf("tmp:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("tmp[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, tmp[i]);

    free(array);
    free(tmp);

    return 0;
}

void foo(double *array, size_t size, double *result)
{
    int i;

    if (result == NULL)
    {
        result = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            result[i] = array[i] + 1;
    }
    else if (result == array)
    {
        double *tmp = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));
        memcpy(tmp, array, size * sizeof(double));

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            tmp[i]++;

        free(array);
        result = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если внутри функции нужно изменять, то нужно использовать двойной указатель.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(double **, size_t, double **);

int main(void)
{
    const size_t size = 4;

    double *array = NULL;
    double *tmp   = NULL;

    array = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;
    array[3] = 4;

    // После вызова foo, tmp так и остаётся NULL
    foo(&array, size, &tmp);
    foo(&array, size, &array);

    int i;

    printf("array:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("array[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, array[i]);

    printf("tmp:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("tmp[%d] = %.2lf\n", i, tmp[i]);

    free(array);
    free(tmp);

    return 0;
}

void foo(double **array, size_t size, double **result)
{
    int i;

    if (*result == NULL)
    {
        *result = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            (*result)[i] = (*array)[i] + 1;
    }
    else if (*result == *array)
    {
        double *tmp = (double *)malloc(size * sizeof(double));
        memcpy(tmp, *array, size * sizeof(double));

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            tmp[i]++;

        free(*array);
        *result = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо большое)